# Application switcher - Only switch windows open in the current desktop

Tags: catalina, mojave, application-switcher

Can I customize the behavior of the application switcher to only show windows from the current desktop?

**Example:**
If I have only one chrome window open, which is on desktop 1, and I am using desktop 3, then the chrome window shouldn't even show up in my application switcher.

*Current behavior:* Chrome appears in my application switcher and if I select chrome in the switcher, I suddenly move to desktop 1 from desktop 3 *(in the context of the example above).*